# Downloading/webscraping images from python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to download all the images from the website but been unable to do so. How I can download all the images from a specific section of a website and save it to my directory?

The below code exports all the image and saves the image link to a csv file, but I also want the image to save it in my directory also.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/Video-Cards-Video-Devices/Category/ID-38?Tpk=graphics%20card'

req = Request(my_url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})


webpage = urlopen(req).read()
page_soup = soup(webpage, "html.parser")


filename = "abc.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")


headers = "imagelink\n" 
f.write(headers)


snackcrisps = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"divCategories divShops-newegg"})
crispitem = snackcrisps[0]


img = crispitem.findAll("div",{"class":"product_image_div productSmall_image_div_lit"})
img1 = img[0]


for img1 in img:

    img2 = img1.findAll('img')
    imageLink = img2[0].get('src')


    print("imageLink: " + imageLink)

    f.write(imageLink + "\n")

f.close()
```

How can I save the images in my local directory? Help needed!!

Many Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download images from BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37158246/how-to-download-images-from-beautifulsoup)

Comment: I am new to this don't know how to fix it. Can someone fix this for me? Thnks

Answer (score 0):

I used the response to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests) to formulate my answer.

First you need to build the full URL for the image you want. This could be as simple as appending "https:" to the beginning of the image link, or not changing the value at all. You'll have to investigate (review this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)) how to adjust the URLs you find based on whether or not they are relative or absolute.

You'll want to use the `requests` module to make the request for the image.

```
import requests
import shutil

for img1 in img:

    img2 = img1.findAll('img')
    imageLink = img2[0].get('src')
    if not "https:" in imageLink:
        imageLink = "https:" + imageLink

    r = requests.get(imageLink, stream=True)
    if r.response = 200:
        with open("my_file.jpg", 'wb') as f:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```