# Is there a way to scrape image links from requests?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm using requests and bs4 for this project.
I cannot figure out how to scrape a image link from a website

Comment: If the linked question doesn't answer your problem, please edit your post to include the code and issues you're experiencing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37158246/how-to-download-images-from-beautifulsoup