# Download image to a folder using web-scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to download image for the images mentioned in the url using bs4.
My code works to extract the

> ```
> <div class="item-name" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exam-4" aria-expanded=false>
>   <div class="ui-h2">April 2022 <span class="ui-tag grey-transparent">14 Exams</span></div>
> </div>
> <div class="item-details collapse " id="exam-4" data-parent="#exam-month">
>   <div class="row">
>       <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
>           <div class="ui-card hover-scale">
>               <a href="https://example.com/uppsc-acf-rfo" class="card-link exam-cards">
>                   <div>
>                       <span class="icon calendar-icon"></span>
>                       <span class="help__content help__content--small">3 Apr 2022</span>
>                       <span class="ui-tag green-filled">Official</span>
>                   </div>
>                   <div class="footer-container">
>                       <span class="exam-icon">
>                       <img src="https://blogmedia.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/uttar-pradesh-logo-png-8-5bbbec3b.png" height="30">
>                       </span>
>                       <span class="exam-name" title="UPPSC ACF RFO Mains">UPPSC ACF RFO Mains</span>
>                       <span class="exam-cta">
>                       Know More <span class="right-icon"></span>
>                       </span>
>                   </div>
>               </a>
>           </div>
>       </div>
> ```

I am using the following code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'row'})

rowList = []
for row in rows:
    cards = row.find_all('div', {'class':re.compile("^ui-card hover-scale")})
    for card in cards:
        dateStr = card.find('span',{'class':re.compile("^help__content")}).text.strip()
        examName = card.find('span', {'class':'exam-name'}).text
        rowList.append({'date':dateStr,
                        'exam':examName})

df = pd.DataFrame(rowList)
df.to_csv('filename.csv', index=False)
```

Current Output:

```
0  3 Apr 2022  UPPSC ACF RFO Mains
```

Expected Output :

```
0  3 Apr 2022  UPPSC ACF RFO Mains    uttar-pradesh-logo-png-8-5bbbec3b.png
```

And .png stored in another directory.
PS : I am only adding a part of html. There are multiple cards

Comment: Try looking at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37158246/how-to-download-images-from-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'row'})

rowList = []
for row in rows:
    cards = row.find_all('div', {'class':re.compile("^ui-card")})
    for card in cards:
        try:
            dateStr = card.find('span',{'class':re.compile("^help__content")}).text.strip()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            dateStr = 'N/A'
        
        try:
            examName = card.find('span', {'class':'exam-name'}).text
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            examName = 'N/A'
        
        try:
            imgUrl = card.find('img')['src']
            imgFile = imgUrl.split('/')[-1]
            
            # To Write to file
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(imgUrl, imgFile)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            imgFile = 'N/A'        
        
        rowList.append({'date':dateStr,
                        'exam':examName,
                        'img':imgFile})
        


df = pd.DataFrame(rowList)
df.to_csv('filename.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: imgUrl = card.find('img')['src']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. Shall I use another parameter to identify the image?

Comment: nope. Images will always be in the `<img>` tag with a `src` attribute. Just like your previous question, what is happening is there is no `<img>` tag under that particular card. So you can either deal with it using the try/except, or by first checking if there is an `<img>` tag present, and if not, skip over it in the iteration.

Comment: I added a try/except in there.

Comment: This should work as expected, since I am downloading the image from a url, it is giving 403 Forbidden error